I am trying to find out who currently owns patent US728858 Issued to Edgar H. BYER on May 26 1903
I am trying to find out who currently owns the rights to pattent US728858A.  It was issued to Edgar H. Byer on May 26 1903.  It is for the Emmert universal vice # 4 a.

Once a patent expires anyone can practice the technology described by it. Patents of that era expired 17 years from their grant date. Thus, since 1920 the cited patent is available to any and all who want to make a product using the invention. Nobody currently owns the rights since there are no longer any rights to own.
